# Inicio de sesion con Facebook con OAuth en asp mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp, facebook, oauth

Tengo configurado el inicio de sesión en una aplicación web **ASP MVC** con **facebook**, **twitter**, **G+** y **Microsoft**, pero el de **facebook** dejo de funcionar. Leí que **facebook** cambio algunas cosas, saben si hay forma de solucionar el problema y si puedo seguir usando la librería **OAuth** que es la que uso.

El error que me marca es en esta linea:

```
 AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
```

El **error** es que me regresa result.IsSuccessful = false, cuando debería regresar true, como comento, yo no moví codigo ni la configuracion solo dejo de funcionar.

Comment: Hola buenos días para que tu pregunta te quede mejor conformada coloca el error que te esta generando.

Comment: ¿Estás trabajando en local o en un sitio de Internet?

Comment: Estoy trabajando local, pero también lo tengo en Internet y los dos dejaron de funcionar.

Comment: Tienes que buscar los nuevos cambios que aplicó facebook y ver de que forma debes de comunicar tu api con ellos.